# Is it possible to clear the default font for certain TextView after setting default font globally using Calligraphy?

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I have set the default font of my application class in the `onCreate()` method as detailed in the doc of Calligraphy:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.
        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/MetaOT-Medi.otf")
        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
        .addCustomViewWithSetTypeface(CustomViewWithTypefaceSupport.class)
        .addCustomStyle(TextField.class, R.attr.textFieldStyle)
        .build()
);
```

I have got a TextView and would like it to fallback using default system font (e.g. Roboto). May I know how to do it?

Now I circumvent this by copying a set of Roboto font to my assets/fonts folder and then for those TextView I would like to fallback, override the fonts to use it in the xml like `fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"`. Or is there a better solution beside this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, which font do you wan to set to which `TextView` you can set it in XML or pragmatically.

```
 fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
```

> XML Sample Code

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

> pragmatically Sample code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        setTypeFace(view, tf);
```

Comment: I am using this solution right now (which requires me to copy a set of Roboto fonts to `assets/fonts` folder), but the problem is I want it to fallback OS system default font like the problem described here: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/152

Comment: User another library like iconify